# Cómo puedo lograr visualizar el control de rdlc

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Estoy haciendo un reporte en reportviewer, el problema es que si quiero agregar un control me marca el error que muestro, ya había logrado agregarlo pero no sé visualizaba el control en la interfaz y me botaba otros errores alguien sae a qué se debe?
Gracias de antemano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]